# Jquery child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I add event handler to a some elements using query:

```
$('div').mouseover(function () {

                                    });
```

Iinside function I have an element for which we add event function ($(this)).
how can I check inside this function next:

1. Have this "DIV"($(this)) child elements
   "DIV"?
2. Have this "DIV"($(this)) child
       element "DIV" whith height more than
       300?

Comment: Please revise. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: btw, take a look here for a lot of great related snippets http://addyosmani.com/blog/50-jquery-snippets-for-developers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div').mouseover(function () {
   var children = $(this).children("div"); //for immediate child div
   if(children.length > 0){
     alert("'div' child present");  
     for(i=0; i < children.length; i++){
        if(children[i].height() > 300) 
           alert("'div' with height more than 300 present");
   } 

});
```

---

Update:
`children[i].css('height')` can also be used.

Comment: But there are one error in children[i].height(): it works only with such syntax $(children[i]).height()

Comment: @Anton: Hmm. You can use `.css('height')` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop this inside your `mouseover` event code:

```
$(this).children('div').each( function() { // $(this) is your parent <div>
  if ($(this).height() > 300) { // $(this) is the current child <div>
    // Do things here...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside the function, `this` refers to the DIV element.  You can then do anything you wish to learn more about it.

So, to get the child DIVs, you can use `var childDivs = $('div',this);`.